# ¿Origen de la palabra chambear? ¿De donde proviene? ¿A qué se le atribuye?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, colombia, venezuela

¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "chambear"? Es muy aplicada en la jerga latina, aun más en países como Venezuela o Colombia.

Por ejemplo:

> Me voy a chambear

o:

> ¿Vas pa' la chamba?"

Comment: Ayudaría mucho un ejemplo de uso, explicando el contexto, para entender qué se quiere expresar con el término.

Comment: Aunque el término se entiende en Colombia y Venezuela, su origen es México.

Comment: @Diego Ejemplo de uso https://youtu.be/_OzGl5ujvac?t=20s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con el sentido de "trabajo, ocupación, negocio"

> En México, la palabra "chamba" se refiere al trabajo a que alguien se dedica o trabajo u ocupación en General. El vocablo se originó en la década de 1940 entre los braceros mexicanos que se trasladaron a EEUU para ser contratados en las tareas agrícolas; al concluir ésta, acudían a la *Chamber of Commerce*.
>
> fuente: [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chamba)

Esta acepción viene recogida también en el DRAE

> [**chamba**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8VFpOez%7C8VHMHXG)
>
> 2. f. coloq. Am. Cen., Ec. y Méx. Empleo, trabajo.

Aunque la primera acepción  (con el significado de "suerte")

> 1. f. coloq. chiripa.

Parece venir del portugués antiguo "chamba" (según esa misma entrada del DRAE), que significa "[suerte](http://www.wordreference.com/espt/chamba)".

Comment: Sería interesante saber por qué se mencionó a los braceros.

Comment: @aparente001 bracero es cualquiera que realiza trabajos no cualificados, generalmente labores del campo. El uso del término viene de esa clase de trabajadores y no de abogados o ingenieros, etc.

Comment: @DGaleano - Pero se mencionó, "El vocablo se originó en la década de 1940 entre los braceros mexicanos que se trasladaron a EEUU para ser contratados en las tareas agrícolas; al concluir ésta, acudían a la Chamber of Commerce." Ah, acabo de entender, por fin.  Chamber --> *chambear*! Lo increible es que se haya extendido a otros países.

Comment: @aparente001 no es tan increíble que se haya extendido. En los 80 las telenovelas mexicanas era muy difundidas. Además desde hace 18 años Los Simpson son un mecanismo riquísimo de difusión de los modismos mexicanos por latinoamericana porque aquí vemos la version doblada en MX. Para la muestra 20 segundos de video con al menos 3 modismos.mx https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2z4KT6W2q8

Comment: @DGaleano - Gracias.  No me había dado cuenta.  Súper interesante tu comentario.